# delete pages from MySite host site collection page library

Tags: powershell, document-library, my-site

I want to delete the pages from the MySite page library and add new pages to that library.

How to do it with PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

Use the below PowerShell script

```
# Add the PowerShell Snapin  

 $snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}  

 if ($snapin -eq $null)   
 {   
     Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"  
 }  

 # Get the SiteURL  
 $SiteUrl = "https://Thegowtham.sharepoint.com"  

 # Get the WebURL  
 $WebUrl = "https://the gowtham.sharepoint.com/sites/TS"  

 # Get the PageLayout  
 $PageLayoutRelUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomPageLayout.aspx"  

 # Get the Page URL  
 $PageName = "TestSite.aspx"  

 # Get the Title of the Page which is going to get created  
 $PageTitle = "SamplePage"  

 # Initialize the Site Object  
 $Site = Get-SPSite($SiteUrl)  

 # Get the Publishing Site based on the SPSite  
 $PublishingSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite($Site)  

 # Get the SPWeb Object  
 $Web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl  

 # Initialize the PublishingWeb based on the SPWeb  
 $PublishingWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($Web)  

 # Get the PageLayouts Installed on the Publishing Site  
 $Layouts = $ PublishingSite.GetPageLayouts($False)  

 # Get our PageLayout  
 $PageLayout = $Layouts[$PageLayoutRelUrl]  

 # Create a new publishing page.  
 $Page = $ PublishingWeb.AddPublishingPage($PageName, $PageLayout)  

 # Assign the Title for the Page  
 $Page.Title = $PageTitle  

 # Update the Page  
 $Page.Update();  

 # Check in the Page with Comments  
 $Page.CheckIn("Page Created Successfully")  

 # Publish the Page With Comments  
 $Page.ListItem.File.Publish("Page Created Successfully and  Publish Comment")
```

Reference : 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/powershell-script-to-create-publishing-page-using-custom-pagelayout-in-sharepoint-2013
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b6fb9c11-c5df-4efb-ab59-2596810eb400/how-to-add-new-page-to-sitepages-list?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy